# Powershell Get-ChildItem progress question

Tags: performance, powershell, progress, pipeline, get-childitem

So, I've got a set of directories 00-99 in a folder. Each of those directories has 100 subdirectories, 00-99. Each of those subdirectories has thousands of images.

What I'm attempting to do is basically get a progress report while it's computing the average file size, but I can't get that to work. Here's my current query:

```powershell
get-childitem <MyPath> -recurse -filter *.jpeg
| Where-Object { Write-Progress "Examining File $($_.Fullname)" true }
| measure-object -Property length -Average
```

This shows me a bar that updates as each of the files gets processed, but at the end I get back no average file size data. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong, because I figure trying to hack the Where-Object to print a progress statement is probably a bad idea(tm).

Since there are millions and millions of images, this query obviously takes a VERY LONG time to work. get-childitem is pretty much going to be the bulk of query time, if I understand things correctly. Any pointers to get what I want? AKA, my result would ideally be:

```
Starting...
Examining File: \00\00\Sample.jpeg
Examining File: \00\00\Sample2.jpeg
Examining File: \00\00\Sample3.jpeg
Examining File: \00\00\Sample4.jpeg
...
Examining File: \99\99\Sample9999.jpg
Average File Size: 12345678.244567
```

Edit: I can do the simple option of:

```powershell
get-childitem <MyPath> -recurse -filter *.jpeg
| measure-object -Property length -Average
```

And then just walk away from my workstation for a day and half or something, but that seems a bit inefficient =/

Comment: If anyone else is wondering why the example in OP doesn't work, its because the script block passed to the `Where-Object` doesn't return a boolean value. It could if it was changed to this:
```...Where-Object { Write-Progress "Examining File $($_.Fullname)"; $true }...```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this?

```
get-childitem -recurse -filter *.exe | 
      %{Write-Host Examining file: $_.fullname; $_} | 
      measure-object -Property length -Average
```

Comment: Im curious, as Im not as familiar with powershell. The % with expression doesnt change the value of the item being piped or something? Can you explain the expression so I can get greater understanding?

Comment: Basically receive the object, and write it `Write-Host Examining file: $_.fullname;` and pass the object downstream `$_`

Comment: And `%` is same as `ForEach-Object`

Comment: `%` is overloaded, actually.  It's an alias for `ForEach-Object` and it's also the modulo (or modulus) operator.

Comment: Very nice display of the difference between the output to the host, and the objects passing through the pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

A little more detailed progress:

```
$images = get-childitem  -recurse -filter *.jpeg

$images | % -begin { $i=0 } `
-process {  write-progress -activity "Computing average..." -status "Examining File: $image.fullpath ($i of $($images.count))" -percentcomplete ($i/$images.count*100); $i+=1 } `
-end { write-output "Average file size is: $($images | measure-object -Property length -Average)" }
```

Comment: I was curious to try your solution but when I paste your script, powershell shows me ">>". Is there anything missing?

Comment: Ops...I think it's due to missing closing double quotes in the `end` block. I've edited the answer. It should work now. Thanks. +1 for giving it a try and feedback :)

Comment: Now the script runs but write-output returns "Average file size is: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo". If I change last part of code in this way: write-output "Average file size is:" $($images | measure-object -property length -average).Average it seems to work. Still +1. Your post are always instructives. Bye.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. It's true, measure-object takes `inputobject` parameter and I was passing to it the array of objects. Using the pipeline all is resolved. Thanks again. I'm glad you like my answers. +1 for cheered up my answer :D