# Powershell Get-ChildItem progress indication

Tags: powershell, windows-server, get-childitem, recycle-bin, progress-indicator

Is it possible to display any sort of a progress indicator for the following (or similar) command?

```
$dir = 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\'
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB
```

(piping its output to something like `%{Write-Output processing item: $_.fullname; $_}` suggested in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862553/2200678) to "[Powershell Get-ChildItem progress question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862396/powershell-get-childitem-progress-question)" - doesn't seem to work. For instance,

```
$dir = 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\'
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{Write-Output processing item: $_.fullname; $_} | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB
```

... produces no output at all other than the final result (size in GB).

#### Context

On a number of our servers, `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\` (recycle bin directory for the "system" account) contains millions of files, hundreds or thousands of sub-directories (which may also contain a large number of files), and keeps filling up at a rate of 1-3GB/day.

The culprit is a misbehaving "line of business" application on these servers that seems to write a lot of temporary files to the recycle bin. At the moment, it is **not** an option to stop it or to change its behavior.

My priorities are these:

1. Figure out a way to intelligently empty this recycle bin, perhaps based on item age (e.g. permanently delete files and sub-directories older than NN days, and only do it during certain hours - like between 1 and 4am daily)
2. Figure out how to prevent the application from using the recycle bin altogether - e.g. by setting registry values for this account / volume (`NukeOnDelete`, `NeedToPurge` and `MaxCapacity`), or a GPO that mandates permanent file deletion.

The 1st part, clearing the files from the recycle bin using Powershell, seems to require to first get a list of items to delete via `Get-ChildItem` - which takes a long, long time on large directories residing on fairly slow disks.

Is there a way to get an indicator that `Get-ChildItem` is doing something when piped to a `Measure-Object` or a similar command (e.g. number of items it was able to collect so far)?

P.S. The reason I think it might be possible is because `Get-ChildItem` on its own (without a pipe to `Measure-Object`) begins output right away. Utilities like TreeSize seem to be able to show progress while they're "walking" the directory tree and collecting data. `dir /a/s C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\` also begins output right away, even if it takes a long time to complete. Any chance we could get a progress indicator when we pipe it to a `Measure-Object` or a similar command?

Comment: if you want immediate output you can call the .net apis (`.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()` in your case)

Comment: This question somehow ties into the [#19989 -PassThru as common parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19989) request. Wishful thinking: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Write-Host -PassThru | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum` or: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % -PassThru { Write-Host "Processing: $_" } | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum` or even ([`#20121`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20121)): `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Write-Host -PassThru -Format "Processing: $_" | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. A simplified version of what you are doing is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

In the above, you lose visibility to the output of Get-ChildItem because you are sending the output into the pipeline, but you can easily mitigate that by adding to any part of the pipeline a section where you `Write-Host` and then simply put the object back onto the pipeline to have it continue:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { Write-Host $_; $_ } | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

or written another way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { Write-Host $_; Write-Output $_ } | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

Of course, you do not just have to just Write-Host the $_, you can get fancier and do things like accumulate and report on totals and etc.

I see you are attempting to take this approach already, but looks like you accidentally used `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`, which ends up also sending your status text into the pipeline and the number of characters of your status text gets added to the sum of the length of the files you are measuring. LoL. Of course you can fix your code by just fixing that:

```
$dir = 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\'
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{Write-Host processing item: $_.fullname; $_} | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking:

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), like most (well-behaved) PowerShell cmdlets *streams* its output, so a subsequent pipeline segment should see input *as soon as `Get-ChildItem` emits the first object*.

  - The only caveat in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is that sorting a given directory's immediate entries is invariably performed first, behind the scenes, which can take a while in large directories.
- However, enclosing any command in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) invariably cause its [*success-stream* output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) to be collected in full, up front, *before* success-stream output is produced.
  By contrast, output to any *other* output stream surfaces right away.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{Write-Output processing item: $_.fullname; $_} | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB` ... produces no output at all other than the final result (size in GB).

Unlike in the [answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862553/2200678), you're using [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) - which targets the success output stream - rather than [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), and that is what prevents *streaming* the status messages.
Additionally, in this case your status messages become part of the input that is "eaten" by `Measure-Object`- where they distort the result, given that strings too have a `.Length` property - so they don't print at all.

`Write-Host` *bypasses* the success-output stream, and prints *to the display* (in PowerShell v5+ via the *information output stream*), so it is capable of producing *display* (host) output even while success output is being collected via `(...)`.

(Similarly, targeting the *verbose* output stream with [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) would work too, and would give you the option to *conditionally* display progress messages, based on the [`$VerbosePreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#verbosepreference); if you pass it the `-Verbose` switch it'll produce output *unconditionally*)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829541/45375) for guidance on when use of `Write-Host` vs. `Write-Output` is called for.

Comment: Thank you! `Write-Output` was the culprit as @Tolga said - I simply didn't understand how it was different from `Write-Host` and other ways to display something in PS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help you, essentially it uses the .NET API from [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0) and a [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0) to traverse an initial directory. The advantage doing this will be the performance as well as you will be able to track the total length while traversing directories.

```
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
$initialItem = Get-Item 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\' -ErrorAction Stop
$queue.Enqueue($initialItem)
$totalLength = 0

$theOutputGoesHere = while ($queue.Count) {
    $current = $queue.Dequeue()

    $writeProgressSplat = @{
        Activity = 'Total Length: {0, 10} Gb' -f [Math]::Round($totalLength / 1gb, 2)
        Status   = "Processing: '{0}'" -f $current.FullName
    }

    Write-Progress @writeProgressSplat

    try {
        $enum = $current.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
    }
    catch {
        # we can't enumerate this dir, add error handling here
        # or empty to ignore enumeration errors

        # dont remove this!
        continue
    }

    foreach ($item in $enum) {
        $item

        if ($item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            $queue.Enqueue($item)
            continue
        }

        $totalLength += $item.Length
    }
}
```